# What happens when we 'fetch upstream' a forked repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, git-fork

I am learning GitHub and found downstram/upstream concepts for forked repositories. I also went through various documentations/blogs but was not able to clear that what actually happens when we press 'fetch upstream'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git fetch upstream` fetches ("downloads") all the changes from the remote repository `upstream` and stores them locally with the `upstream`. You can then refer to these local copies (e.g., check out to them, set up tracking branching, cherry pick commits, etc) with this prefix. E.g., `git checkout upstream/some-branch` would check out to the local copy of `some-branch` you just fetched from `upstream`.

Answer (score 3):

To understand this properly, you need to know the following about Git:

- Git is all about *commits*.  It's not about files (though commits contain files).  It's not about branches (though branch names help us, and Git, find commits).  It's really about the *commits*.
- Commits are numbered.  The numbers are huge, ugly, random-looking things expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal); each commit gets a unique number, different from every other commit in every Git repository everywhere.  If two different Git repositories have the same commit *number* in them, they have the same *commit* in them: the number *is* the commit, in a sense (though you have to have the commit itself: the number is just the key, in the [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), that Git uses to *look up*, i.e., find, the commit).
- Besides *branch* names like `main` or `master`, `dev`, `feature/tall`, etc., Git has other names: tag names like `v3.14`, and things called *remote-tracking names* (Git actually calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find that it makes more sense if you leave out the unnecessary word *branch* here).  Each name gets to store one (1) hash ID.  That's all we need, because *commits* **also** store hash IDs.

When we clone a Git repository, we get *all of the other repository's commits* and *none of their branches*.<sup>1</sup>  Instead of branch names, our Git takes the other clone's branch names and turns them into our *remote-tracking names*.  If we call the other Git—the one we're cloning now—`origin`, which is the standard first *remote* name, their `main` turns into our `origin/main`, their `dev turns into our` origin/dev`, and so on.

What this means is that our branch names are *ours*.  We don't have to use the same names as some other Git repository.  We usually do, just for sanity, but we don't *have to*.

This also tells us, indirectly, *what* a "remote" is: a *remote* is a short name that stores a URL—the URL we're cloning from, for `origin`—and also provides a prefix for the remote-tracking names.  The `origin` in `origin/dev` comes from the *remote* name `origin`.<sup>2</sup>

When you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

your Git software, working in your repository, calls up some other Git software somewhere—at the URL stored under the name `origin`—and has it connect to some other repository using that URL.  That other software (the "other Git", as it were) reads out their commits—specifically the hash IDs—and branch names and sends them to "our Git" (our software working in our repository).  Our Git and their Git have a mini-conversation involving the hash IDs, so that our Git can see what commits they have, that we don't.

Our Git will then bring over any (new-to-us) commits they have, that we don't.  That includes any commits we manually, carefully discarded from our Git repository because we found they were bad in some way:<sup>3</sup> so in this respect, it's like having Git-sex with a Git that may be carrying some virus, and we'll just keep getting re-infected until they *also* ditch that bad commit.  But mostly this is good since mostly we *do* want every commit they have, that we don't.

But: what about `upstream`?  Well, there's a minor problem with this word, *upstream*, because Git uses this *same word* to mean something else.<sup>4</sup>  But in this case, `upstream` is the name GitHub in particular encourage people to use as the **second remote** in their Git repositories.  We can have more than one remote!

Using `git remote add upstream url`, we create a *second* remote named `upstream`.  After that:

```
git fetch upstream
```

uses the saved URL to call up some other Git, just like `git fetch origin` does.  Whether the hosting site is GitHub, or some other site, our Git and their Git have the same kind of conversation as before.  Our Git will find out which commits they have that we don't, download those commits into our Git repository, and create or update remote-tracking names like `upstream/main` and `upstream/dev`.  We'll get one `upstream/*` name for each branch name in the other git at the URL stored under the name `upstream`.

That's almost all there is to it.  There is one particular point that trips people up here though.  Suppose you `git clone` a repository, so that you now have `origin/main` and `origin/feature/tall`.  But the `origin` repository is forked from some other repository, so you use `git remote add` to add your `fork2` or `upstream` or whatever you want to call it, and then you run:

```
git fetch fork2
```

or whatever you called it.  You now have `fork2/main` and `fork2/feature/tall`.  So you have both `origin/feature/tall` and `fork2/feature/tall`.

*You have not yet made your own `feature/tall`.*  You run:

```
git switch feature/tall
```

or:

```
git checkout feature/tall
```

expecting your Git to create your `feature/tall` from ... well, wait: are you expecting your new branch name, `feature/tall`, to spring from `origin/feature/tall` and use that as its upstream setting?  Or are you expecting your new branch name, `feature/tall`, to spring from `fork2/feature/tall` and use *that* as its upstream?  Or perhaps you need *two* `feature/tall` branches, one to go with `origin/feature/tall` and one to go with `fork2/feature/tall`.

*You can't call both `feature/tall`.*  This means that if you *do* want two branch names, one for each remote-tracking name, you will be forced to break the usual "my name = my remote-tracking name, minus the remote" setup that you're used to.  **The bottom line is that as soon as you have two or more remotes, your Git life gets more complicated.**  There's no way around this: you *must* understand what remotes, and remote-tracking names, are and do.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can modify this behavior somewhat at `git clone` time, and there are usually trash and/or dropped commits in repositories that get cleaned up by maintenance commands later and `git clone` normally doesn't copy those.  So this is just an approximation, useful for understanding things.

<sup>2</sup>As usual with Git, the process by which `git fetch origin` results in their `dev` becoming `origin/dev` is not straightforward at all.  You can do all kinds of crazy things with this.  For sanity, though, it's not wise to do anything weird and wild here in any normal user clone: just let their `dev` become your `origin/dev`.

<sup>3</sup>Perhaps, for instance, we carefully discarded an accidental commit that added a terabyte database that was clogging up the disk.  Oops, here it is again!

<sup>4</sup>In particular, Git allows each *branch name* to store a single *upstream name*.  Usually we'll set the upstream of branch `br1` to `origin/br1`: the remote-tracking name at `origin` that corresponds to *their* branch name `br1`.  That way *our* branch name `br1` can easily refer to our `origin/br1`, which is our copy—our Git's memory—of *their* branch name `br1`.

This is not at all the same as a *remote* named `upstream`.  If GitHub encouraged people to use, as the second remote name, `fork2` or similar, that might help.